# dynamic layout with two buttons problem

Tags: android

how can I set my buttons in a linearLayout dynamically? So I want that all android mobiles with different display sizes can use my app.

Code

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout_main2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button android:id="@+id/bt1" android:text="GO"   
style="@style/button_font" android:clickable="false"     
android:background="@drawable/box1" 
android:layout_marginLeft="6px" />

<Button android:id="@+id/bt2" android:text="ON"   
style="@style/button_font" android:clickable="false"     
android:background="@drawable/box1" 
android:layout_marginLeft="6px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Style-Code

```
<style name="button_font" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">44px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">39px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 
 <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" style="@style/button_font"  
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `android:layout_weight = "1"` for two button, then it take same screen ratio.

Means 1:1 ratio is put for the two buttons. So it works in all screen sizes.

Comment: ok, can yopu explain me what is android:layout_weight exactly doing?

Comment: android:layout_weight & android:layout_height will decide your button(or any control) size.

Comment: its just like ratio....if you give two button corresponding weight 2 and 1, then you can see the difference. if your screen width is 480 then the first button will take 320dp and next 160dp